# Workbench automatic logout Issue &Automtically redirecting to login page

Tags: workbench

First we are logged in salesforce,then we are openning workbench trying to connect and Login to salesforce,Then the expectation should be we should be able to login and perform our operations,But here it is automatically redirecting login page.
please find the screenshot attched.
[image]

Thanks &Regards
Kartheek R S

Comment: Same here. Changing the API version to 57.0 does not solve the issue.

Comment: Don't forget "Workbench is free to use, but is not an official salesforce.com product. Workbench has not been officially tested or documented."
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nURes.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nURes.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your user settings in Salesforce, you can revoke the OAuth access for workbench. Workbench will then try to re-authenticate when you login again. Sometimes the login is working, sometimes you get immediately redirected back to the login page.

For me this was getting too annoying and I switched to Data Loader, which you can download from Settings > Data Management > Data Loader in Salesforce.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue. Eventually what worked for me was

1. Clearing the cache on my browser
2. Switching browser (Chrome worked for me, Firefox did not)

After I cleared the cache in Chrome, I was able to log in and run queries using the Bulk API without being continually redirected back to the login page.

Comment: This didn't work for me, tried in Incognito